# Does WordPress support WebP images?

Tags: plugin-development

Recently, I got news that from now WordPress will support WebP images. It would be amazing if it supports webp images directly.

But I don't think so that WordPress has taken any decisions on it.

Does WordPress support WebP images?

Comment: Wordpress 5.8 will come with support for webp images

Answer (score 4):

On July 20th 2021, assuming everything goes to plan, WordPress 5.8 will be released with full support for WebP images.

You can read all about that here:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/07/wordpress-5-8-adds-webp-support/

If you like you can use the [beta testing plugin](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/beta-testing/) to test it out on your WordPress site if you can't wait until it's released.

Comment: Thank you so much paul for your kind and quick response. I would definitely read the post.

Comment: No problem at all! Feel free to accept answers to questions you post, if you feel they have helped you :)

Comment: Note that you will need a server that supports this, not all servers will be able to but it's easy for your host to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload Webp in the media library, you can always add the mime type using the filter. Paul G. already answered your initial question so I am not going to write about that.

```
/**
 * Allow .webp Upload
 */
function my_custom_mime_types( $mimes ) {
    
        // New allowed mime types.
        $mimes['webp'] = '  image/webp';

    return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_custom_mime_types' );
```